# Stanley-Reisner Ring (Beginner Question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

[image]

I understand that $I_\Delta$ is generated by "square-free monomials corresponding to the non-faces of $\Delta$".

Why isn't $x_2x_3x_4$ one of the generators of $I_\Delta$ in this case?

I have some confusion/misunderstanding regarding the definition.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $x_2x_3x_4$ is a multiple of $x_3x_4$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Oh right... I understand now.